# hsqldb schema creation

Tags: spring, jdbc, hsqldb

I have some troubles with this problem: when user starts an application(web-based on Spring) for the first time, it should automatically create a schema (e.g. "MY_SCHEMA") and create 2 tables. Then it can work with them. But if application starts again, the "MY_SCHEMA" should be already exist, so the application should only load this schema without creating tables and so on...

How to it?

Answer (score 0):

HSQLD is primary used as a memory database. You can change your tables to persistent tables. It is documented [here](http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/sqlgeneral-chapt.html#N103BB).

Another option that I prefere is to use another database like MySql that by default persists the tables to disk.

Answer (score 0):

HSQLDB can be configured to run both with an in-memory database and a database persisted in a file. Please check the documentation available on HSDBL website (http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/ch01.html#N100F3). I think you're settings use the in-memory database.

Espen is right, HSQLDB is usually used as an in-memory database.